# Pastebin API Confusion

Tags: php, api, post, pastebin

So, I'm using Pastebin's API (https://pastebin.com/api#9) to list a users posts. But based on what it says, it seems like you need to know the password of the user to list the pastes?

PHP Script:

```
$api_dev_key        = 'DEV KEY';
$api_user_key       = 'USER KEY';
$api_results_limit  = '100';
$url            = 'https://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php';
$ch             = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'api_option=list&api_user_key='.$api_user_key.'&api_dev_key='.$api_dev_key.'&api_results_limit='.$api_results_limit.'');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);

$response       = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;
```

In order to get the user key you need (Dev key, Username and Password), why do you need their credentials to list their pastes? Are there any ways to do it without them?

Comment: Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Generate api_userkey here:

> https://pastebin(dot)com/api/api_user_key.html

No need to generate it ever again unless you need to. You need to use accompanied with your api_dev_key. Also I highly recommend using this package:

> https://github.com/gebn/Brush